# Vim regular expression for backslash

Tags: regex, vim

I'm inputting LaTeX source into a source file for another language, which means lots of escaping.

I'm having a bit of trouble constructing a regular expression that matches only a single backslash, followed by any number of alphanumerics using Vim regular expressions.  My tries, so far, have included:

```
/[^\\]\\[^\\]+/
```

including many combinations of escaping.  What am I missing?

After a bit more trial and error, it looks like when I do:

```
/\\[^\\]+
```

vim is trying to match a backslash followed by any non-backslash followed by a literal +

Comment: It didn't.  I escaped them, just as it said.

Comment: @hwnd: pattern not found (though I'm looking at "\ldots" in the source)

Comment: You should escape the `+` sign; change to `\+` presuming you want "one or more non-backslash characters"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `+` quantifier here as well.

```
/\\[^\\]\+/
```